# How to use Regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I'm needing to use a regex function for a project, where an input needs to match a regex I have set exactly

After having done some research I wasn't able to find a definitive way to go about the problem as I was seeing some similar but different examples almost everywhere.

```cpp
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

std::regex place = "(place)\\s[ROYGBP][0-5]\\s(at)\\s[A-Z][0-9]{1,2}";
std::cin >> choice;
if(std::regex_match(choice, place)){
  return true;
}
return false;
```

I expected this to go through but the compiler is rejecting it with

```
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char[46]" to "std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char>>"
```

Comment: `std::regex place("(place)\\s[ROYGBP][0-5]\\s(at)\\s[A-Z][0-9]{1,2}");`

Comment: Also, use `regex_search` if you want a partial match

Comment: Just a heads up: native `regex library` was added to C++ only from C++ 11. So if your compiler doesn't support C++11, you may get a lot of errors

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is at `std::regex place = "(place)\\s[ROYGBP][0-5]\\s(at)\\s[A-Z][0-9]{1,2}";` - I believe it happens because that's not correct syntax for initializing a regex. Try this instead:

`std::regex place = std::regex("(place)\\s[ROYGBP][0-5]\\s(at)\\s[A-Z][0-9]{1,2}");`

Be sure you're compiling with the `--std=c++11` (or higher) flag; otherwise, the compiler is going to get frustrated with you! According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), this functionality wasn't added until C++11. The site also has great resources on the syntax for regex; it's what I used to build my regex projects.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is based on a [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58233561/509868) by the user [VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt))

`std::regex` constructor taking a single pointer to char argument is `explicit` so it can not be invoked using copy initialization syntax. Use direct list initialization syntax instead:

```
std::regex place{"(place)\\s[ROYGBP][0-5]\\s(at)\\s[A-Z][0-9]{1,2}"};
```

Or use the same constructor but change the syntax so it permits `explicit` initialization:

```
std::regex place("(place)\\s[ROYGBP][0-5]\\s(at)\\s[A-Z][0-9]{1,2}");
```